# How to close silly feature-requests on Meta SO?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

I just came across [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281214/making-a-chat-room-for-banned-users) asking for a pretty silly (IMHO) feature-request:

> I suggest to make a chat room for users who have question/answer bans and need them to be lifted.
>   this room has to be created by moderators(that's why I didn't create it) so banned people chat there, say what edits they've tried but didn't make any results, ask moderators if the question/answer is good after edit, and how to encourage people to vote for undelete or reopen.

Is there a feasible close reason (without searching for a duplicate), I could use for this question?

I know, mods can just apply the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag and close the question. I'm asking what we mere mortals can do to close such question?

Comment: if there isn't.... there should be.

Comment: a meta question about a meta question.  How...meta  ;)

Comment: Why would the fact that you disagree with the proposal warrant its closure? Supply an answer explaining why the proposal is bad. Or just downvote it. `status-declined` doesn't close the question either AFAIK. Though it indicates further discussion may well be pointless.

Comment: @MartinSmith _"why the proposal is bad"_ I've been leaving a number of comments there, why I think so. But you're right, that's apparently not enough, without stating them clearly within this question. To be honest, I wanted to raise up a kind of meta-meta effect about that particular question, after trying to find a valid close reason.

Comment: I thought of informing about the Tavern on the Meta, but then I see no usefulness in the OP's post, so I let it go.

Comment: @InfiniteHappiness Yeah, I should have been asking there 1st probably. I just don't like the chat-rooms so much :-P .... (I should learn more how to use my _tools at hand_)

Comment: we mere mortals can find a dupe and close as such (this involves the need to keep a "canonical copy" of a given kind of silly request)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We normally just stick to downvoting the question to oblivion. That alone is usually enough to convey the message. After all, on meta, downvotes on a suggestion indicate disagreement.

Being silly does not make a feature request off-topic. It just makes it an unrealistic feature request. Someone could still respond with either a smartass remark, or a good explanation as to why the feature doesn't make sense (which can even be useful in the unlikely event somebody else comes up with the same outrageous idea in the future).

Answer (score 3):

The general principle of closing is not different on Meta: **if there is a close reason that applies, use it.** You may want to also comment so that you get help from other people who can close. For instance, maybe you see something as being unclear in the question. Not everybody will necessarily see the unclarity you noticed. (For instance, some people may stop reading early and downvote without reading the whole post.) A comment may help others see what you saw and vote to close with you.

If there is no close reason that fits, then you can only downvote.